# How did I loose -1 rep?

Tags: support, review-queues, reputation-history

Maybe I'm blind but I can't find any meta questions about loosing one rep for something review related.

[image]

It links to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29085013/728393) which I [reviewed here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/7364762).

My review was `-1`, comment and then `I'm done`

1 rep doesn't matter but there is no explanation...

No one else reviewed the question. The question wasn't an audit. The question wasn't deleted.

What is that `-1` supposed to tell me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You downvoted that answer.  That costs you 1 rep.

Comment: Huh, I should probably have known that. I guess I don't downvote answers much.

Comment: So your reputation suffers for rightly pointing out terrible answers? That's stupid.